# Cannot transform, scale or move (aka edit) vertices, faces or edges - X,Y,Z locked

Tags: edit-mode, vertices, scale

I'm using 2.8. Yesterday I had no issues editing my mesh. Now, after I select vertices (faces or edges) I cannot scale or move it for editing- it feels locked. I turned proportional editing on and off. I also tried using cursor, move, transform, etc. Maybe I accidentally pressed something. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It worked after I removed a shape key and turned on shape key edit mode.

I'm not sure why I wasn't able to edit the other shape key. Any input is welcome. See pic.

[image]